# send_mail not working on production

Tags: python, email, django-1.7, suse

If I am running the website on my development machine, website will be able to send emails via send_mail perfectly with 0 errors.
But, If I deploy it on the production server I will get (Timeout Error).
I tried both send_mail and EmailMessage. This is my settings file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'me@mail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'me@mail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = '00.000.00.000' #server IP
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'me-mail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
```

Production server is running SUSE Enterprise.

Comment: Timeout Error means a problem connecting to the server. So either the port is wrong (25 is for SMTP plain, and TLS has a different port number); or that the host is not reachable from your production server, or that there is some firewall rule preventing a connection. Really, too many variables to troubleshoot unless you do your own digging. This question is tagged with python, python-3.x and python-3.4 - unless its a Python problem, no need to be version specific.

Comment: Are you sure the EMAIL_HOST is correct? The server might not be reachable through its external address, you might need to use `127.0.0.1`. It may also be possible that the server requires you to use TLS or STARTSSL.

Comment: Actually, the production server is different than the mail server. and as I mentioned, email does reach to the mail server in development environment but, not on production.